# Destroy JQuery draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a set of elements that are draggable. How can I remove draggable function?

1. `$('.draggable').draggable('disable')` is not an option in my case
2. `$('.draggable').draggable('destroy')` returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined`

Comment: how is the draggable created

Comment: Both are valid...http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy  and http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-disable

Comment: If all you want is to remove draggable function why is disable no an option?

Comment: Make sure all elements with class of "draggable" actually are "draggable-enabled" and to attempt destroying only those that are. I would need to test it, but I suspect you would get that undefined if you were destroying something that isn't there.

Comment: seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cY6ZY/

Comment: jquery and ui versions used

Comment: Changed Arun's fiddle a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/cY6ZY/1/ - if you call it again on a destroyed element it does throw an error. At least in jquery 1.9.1 and ui 1.9.2. Which could point to your .draggable not being draggable at all (or anymore).

Comment: @cernunnos because I need to enable it later for another set of elements

Comment: @ArunPJohny jquery-1.7.1 & jquery-ui-1.8.23

Comment: @EvidentAgenda sounds like my case. I do add and destroy draggable few times

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the jQuery UI API:

**destroy()**

Removes the draggable functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.

```
This method does not accept any arguments.
```

Code examples:

Invoke the destroy method:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "destroy" );
```

**EDIT**

As this seems to not work properly for you - and it's an issue being seen all around the jQuery forums - that's a proposed fix:

```
ui.draggable.draggable("option", "revert", false);
```

Comment: from my question: "$('.draggable').draggable('destroy') returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"

Comment: Sorry for not reading it properly before posting. I've edited my answer.

Comment: `$(".selector").draggable.draggable("option", "revert", false);`  is not working... am I missing something?

Comment: @ImranBughio, `$(".selector")` isn't the same as `ui` here. Please review your code.

Comment: If i try `ui` i get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined(…)`

Comment: @ImranBughio, you should then post a question. It's not really recommended to ask over the comments, as we would need more details, code examples, etc, to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check before destroying

```
if ($el.data('ui-draggable')) { // error to call destroy if not there
  $el.draggable('destroy');
}
```

In jQuery >2.1.0 it's 'ui-draggable'