# JQuery UI Draggable Modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have a modal with dragging functionality.  It works fine, but when I close and reopen the modal it retains its last position.  For example, if I drag the modal to the bottom of the window and close it, when I reopen the modal it's at the bottom of the window.  I need it to be centered as it was the first time it was launched.  I am using `JQuery UI` and `Bootstrap` here.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="outerContainer">
....
....
        <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="alertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="alertModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" id="contentModal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="alertModalLabel">Add Alert</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Maintenance/_AddAlert.cshtml", Model.AlertViewModel);
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script>
     $(function () {
            $("#alertModal").draggable({
                handle: ".modal-header",
                scroll: false,
                containment: '#outerContainer'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: destroy it on modal close : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15551781/2454790 and drag it on modal open...

Answer (score 1):

When you close/open it you can hook into the modal events and re-position accordingly:

```
$('#alertModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // reposition modal according to window / viewport here
});
```

See [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) where it talks about hooking into events.

HTH

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't know how to restore the original position when the modal was first loaded.

Comment: You can't really store the initial position and re-use it (because the user could resize the window) - it'd have to be a calculation of the width of the modal compared to the width of the view point (screen.width()), similar WRT height, and setting left and top accordingly.